# Count number of objects and print the count in real-time video using SSD MobileNet Object detection model

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, conv-neural-network, object-detection

I want to count the number of objects detected per label and print it on the screen when the object detection model is run over a real-time video feed. what is the code for doing so? I have used an SSD MobileNet v2 pre-configured model for CNN tasks. I am detecting 3 labels, hunter, elephant and ranger.

```
while True: 
ret, frame = cap.read()
image_np = np.array(frame)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}
detections['num_detections'] = num_detections

# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=5,
            min_score_thresh=.6,
            agnostic_mode=False)

cv2.imshow('object detection',  cv2.resize(image_np_with_detections, (400, 400)))

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    cap.release()
    break
```

Comment: You need to keep a counter of each of the three labels and update them upon detection. Using `cv2.putText()` you can print the values on the screen

Comment: Could you please provide a sample code pn how to increment and decrement that counter function?

Comment: What does `detections['num_detections']` return? If it returns the count, you can print that

Comment: It returns a fixed value of 100 although the image I'm using for detection has only 1 to 2 objects

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this at my end. Please go through https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py to see if get something

Comment: Alright. Thanks a lot for the help.